# How to define a selected number of variables from a two-dimensional set in Zimpl?

Tags: scip

I have an index set `A` and another set `dim`, and I need to define variables `x[i,j]` where `i` is in `A` and `j` starts from one and is `<= dim[A]` for each member of A:

`set A := { 11 .. 20}; 
dim := {<11>1, <12>3, <13>1, <14>1, <15>5, <16>1, <17>2, <18>1, <19>1, <20>3};`

For example, in the above, I will have:

`x[11,1], x[12,1], x[12,2], x[12,3], x[13,1], x[14,1], ...`

I can do something like:

`set B := { 1 .. maxDim)};
var x[A *B];`

where `maxDim` is the maximum number in `dim`. How can I do this without creating many extra variables?

Comment: This is not possible with ZIMPL. I would recommend to partition your set AxB into subsets containing variables with the same dimension. Since ZIMPL is not very dynamic, you need to know the maximal dimensions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the question. What is dimlist indexed with?
What would be the size of the dimensions 3..5 
Likely the best way to achieve this is to have a full dimensional table
and just exclude the ones you do not like, e.g.

```
set I := { <a,b,c,d,e,f> in A*B*C*D*E*F with a > b or whatever restriction you like };

var x[I];
```

or you can mess around with the bounds of the variables like in

```
var x[<a,b,c,d,e,f> in AxB*D3*D4*D5] real <= (if dimlist[a,b] > 0 ? dimlist[a,b] : 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found a solution, which I think should work:

`var x[ <i, j> in A*B with j <= dim[i]];`